# Connection refused, while connecting to upstream on engintron/nginx deployment

Tags: node.js, nginx, next.js, cpanel, pm2

I've dealt with this error in the nginx error log for the past few hours.

```
*2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: my ip, server: my domain, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "my domain"
```

I'm currently trying to deploy a next.js app with nginx using engintron for CPanel as well as pm2.

default.conf

```
server {
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=off;

    server_name my domain domain-ip;

    # deny all; # DO NOT REMOVE OR CHANGE THIS LINE - Used when Engintron is disabled to block Nginx from becoming an open proxy

    # Set the port for HTTP proxying
    set $PROXY_TO_PORT 8080;

    include common_http.conf;
```

common_http.conf

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

There aren't any errors on pm2's front, and `sudo nginx -t` works just fine, so I'm confused on what exactly the issue is.

Any sort of help is appreciated, have a good rest of your day :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, for some reason my pm2 wasn't working properly, after a clean reinstall I got this issue fixed, but now I've got a 404 not found for my index file, the fun life of being a developer lol